# JsonSerializer.Deserialize is returning empty object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I have a webapi that returns some Json:

```json
{"id":9,"businessName":"dummy","address":"pluto","products":[
{"id":762,"description":"Centralized needs-based website","price":1281.24,"stock":1600,"categories":[],"factory":null},
{"id":1027,"description":"Realigned 6th generation knowledge base","price":2398.16,"stock":19583,"categories":[],"factory":null},
{"id":1392,"description":"User-centric zero administration array","price":998.07,"stock":6124,"categories":[],"factory":null},
{"id":1800,"description":"Team-oriented reciprocal core","price":4422.95,"stock":17372,"categories":[],"factory":null},
{"id":2763,"description":"Sharable needs-based hierarchy","price":4122.98,"stock":17397,"categories":[],"factory":null},
{"id":6189,"description":"Re-engineered hybrid emulation","price":395.09,"stock":532,"categories":[],"factory":null}
]}
```

I then try to deserialize using:

```cs
using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{GetApiRouteFromEntity(entity)}/{entity.GetId()}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        T? item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseContent);
```

but this gives me an empty Factory with id 0 and all the other attributes to null

*Factory.cs*

```cs
public class Factory : EntityBase
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Nome Business")]
        public string? BusinessName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Indirizzo")]
        public string? Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Prodotti")] 
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"[{Id}] {BusinessName}";
        }
    }
```

*Product.cs*

```cs
public class Product : EntityBase
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Descrizione")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Prezzo")]
        public float Price { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Magazzino")]
        public int Stock { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Categorie")]
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Fabbrica")]
        public virtual Factory Factory { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"[{Id}] {Description}";
        }
    }
```

*EntityBase.cs*

```cs
public abstract class EntityBase
    {
        public virtual object GetId()
        {
            return GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(this);
        }
    }
```

i guess its because the factory prop in the products is null but idk how to work around that

Comment: responseContent  is full with the Json at the end of the request, but the serializer just retunrs an empty entity

Comment: So `T` in `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseContent)` is `Factory` ?

Comment: yes, in fact when debugging item is a Factory but it has every prop as default value

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. There is no : between "products" and its array

Comment: i just pasted the json incorrectly, ty for making me notice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0):

> By default, property names and dictionary keys are unchanged in the JSON output, including case.

You can specify the property naming policy:

```cs
T? item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseContent, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
});
```

to use camel case for all JSON property names, or mark all needed properties with `JsonPropertyNameAttibute` containing correct name:

```cs
public class Factory : EntityBase
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")] // and so on
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Or set [`JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=net-7.0) to `true`.

Comment: oh my god, i spent 5 hoiurs into this, ty so much!

Comment: @IvanAmbla was glad to help!

Comment: i have a new problem now :-:, if i try to serialize the object it gives me a nice string with PascalCase but if i try and use JsonSerializer.Serialize(lastEntity.Entity,new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }) it just gives me {}

Comment: @IvanAmbla are you using the same settings when serializing and deserialiazing? Or the json is coming from another system?

Comment: same settings, im just putting instead of getting

Comment: for now i found a workaround using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject but it would be better using the native jsonserializer

Comment: Can you please post full repro somewhere? Cause if you are using the same settings as in answer it should not return pascal case. There is another option - make property names case insensitive - `new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };`

Comment: using the same options returns {} using no options return Pascal, ill prepare a repo if necessary i will take me some time, ty for the help again!

Comment: i can open a new discussion, i think its better since even if related is a different problem ill open it this evening

Answer (score 13):

The JSON keys are all camel case but the props in your classes are written in pascal case. E.g. `businessName` vs. `BusinessName`. Hence JsonSerializer can't match them.

You can initialize the serializer like this to ignore the differences in casing:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
T? item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseContent, options);
```

See the docs for further info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing